# What is the minimum number of bootstraps to be done using bca non-parametric method

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to use the `boot()` and `boot.ci()` functions from `library("boot")` for very large data sets(~50 000) with `type="bca"`.

If R(number of bootstraps) is too small, it will give the following error:

```
Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  : 
  estimated adjustment 'a' is NA
```

I wouldn't want it to be too large either.

What is a good number for R? I know it would depend on the size of the data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a greater number of bootstraps, in general, for confidence intervals than for estimates. I have heard suggestions of 1000 bootstraps for estimates and 10000 for confidence intervals since computing power has increased in the last decade.

The `boot()` function nowadays has argument `parallel` which can run the bootstraps on multiple cores, which if compute time is a concern for you, you might look to use to reduce significantly the time it takes to run the analysis on data sets of your size.

Comment: I tried it on data of size 1000 with R= 10000. But it gave the following error: "Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  : estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite". Does it mean that the R is too big or too small?

Comment: The estimated value of the correction required is infinite. Look at the distribution of the bootstrap values; are they very strongly skewed? You might need to do many more than 10,000 to solve the problem.

Comment: I noticed that anything less than the sample size throws the error when running boot with bca